# $5(x + 2) + 2(x-3) < 3(x - 1) + 4x$ leads to nowhere, but why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

It looks like extremely simple, but I'm totally confused
\begin{align*}
5(x + 2) + 2(x-3) & < 3(x - 1) + 4x\\
5x + 10 + 2x - 6 & < 3x - 3 + 4x\\
7x - 4 & < 7x - 3\\
7x - 7x & < -3 + 4\\
0 & < 1 
\end{align*}

How is that?!!

Why do I lost $x$ variable and it leads to nowhere?!
Thanks

Comment: If you had done the computations correctly, it would just tell you the original inequality holds for every $x$. But you didn't...

Comment: How can it hold for all $x$? Setting $x=0$ gives $4<-3$ which is clearly false.

Comment: There is a mistake on line 3 of the computation. The $-4$ should be $+4$.

Comment: What is the point in making minor edits to a decade old question???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simplify, you obtain the inequality $7x+4 < 7x-3$ which is the same as $4<-3$. Since this is never true, the inequality is false, regardless of the value of $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Getting a result like $0<1$ means that the claim is true for all x. In other words, for any $x$ you input, the inequation holds true. (For all of your steps taken were equivalent to their predecessor, and as such did not change the truth/false value of the inequation. In some cases, mathematicians like to denote that by adding "$\Leftrightarrow$" at the start of each line.)

And there is a error in your computation aswell. I know no (reasonable) definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $10-6=-4$

Comment: Careful:  Proving a true statement from an assumption often does NOT mean the assumption is true.  (In this case it does, but more should be said).

Comment: Mmh. Do you mean I should mention that all of the steps taken are equivalent to their predecessor?

Comment: @JasonDeVito:  It does when the steps are reversible, which they are here (and correct, too, which needs some work)

Comment: Yup, that would fix it.

Comment: @Ross:  I hadn't even looked at the actual computations for correctnes ;-).  And yes, of course the key idea here is that all the steps are reversible.

Comment: Someone just downvoted all answers. Felt no need to explain however.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The conclusion you came to means that for all $x$ the inequality you stated is true

EDIT: As De Vito pointed out, if you arrive correctly at a false statement this  necessarily means that the assumption is false. In other words if the implication $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true and $Q$ is false then $P$ is also false.

But, if you arrive correctly at a true statement, this doesn't necessarily mean that the assumption is true. For that you will need $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ and not simply $P\Rightarrow Q$. In our case, you have shown $5(x + 2) + 2(x-3) < 3(x - 1) + 4x\Leftrightarrow 4<-3$

Comment: $0<1$ is true. You might want to fix that and you receive an upvote.

Comment: No, it is true for all $x$.

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: Careful:  Proving a true statement from an assumption often does NOT mean the assumption is true.  (In this case it does, but more should be said).

Comment: The statement is never true.

Comment: Mind using \Leftrightarrow instead of \leftrightarrow in your LaTeX formatting? The latter is wrong ;)

Comment: That's actually the opposite of what I pointed out.  If the implication $P\rightarrow Q$ is true and $Q$ is **false**, then $P$ must also be false.  But if $Q$ is **true**, you learn nothing about $P$ at all.

Comment: (Thanks.  I'll delete all my comments in a second)

Comment: Check the computation, it cannot be true that $5(x + 2) + 2(x-3) < 3(x - 1) + 4x\Leftrightarrow 0<1$, because the left hand side is equivalent to $4 < -3$.

Comment: Well, your statement is correct, but the $4 <3$ should be $4 < -3$ (the truth value is the same, of course, but presumably you meant to link the inequality directly with the original one).

Comment: @copper.hat Corrected

Answer (score 0):

It's like $a_{1}y+a_{1}y+……a{n}y+C<b_{1}y+b_{2}y+……b{m}y+D$

if$\sum a_{i}=\sum b_{j}$ the unkown y will certainly disappear.
You can think like this.

Let A=1+2+4

Let B=3+5+(-1)

Then A=B, A and B are coefficient of y for the left and right.

Then y disappear.